# SignalR: How to change a value (timer) from different page?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I thought maybe you could push me to the right direction. I'm struggling with a simple issue (hard for me). I have a SignalR countdown page working fine. Now I'm writing a kind of administration page (.aspx) (with start/stop and reset timer functionality), but I'm not able to change the timer/countdown value. 
My point here is: I want to change it from a different page.

Many thanks in advance,

N.

Comment: Could you show your server- and client- side code for the countdown part currently working, so that we can suggest *deltas* instead of a full solution?

Answer (score 0):

store the value as 'global' in cookie or session or localstorage or clientside sqlite or anything depending on the types of client in page1,  if page2 wants to change the value in page1, simply modify these global variables.  e.g. When page1 starts a timer, check the new value from the global variables first!